# Model is not saved after the get() method (Laravel, PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the get() method to retrieve the model from the database. When i want to modify a field with the save button i am getting that error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save();

Here is my code:

```
public static function authenticate($token='randomToken'){
$u = User::where('token',$token)// $token)
    ->get(['token']);
if ($u->count()==1){//User is authenticated
    $u->token = User::getGUID();
    $u->save();
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

public static function getGUID()
{
if (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
    return com_create_guid();
} else {
    mt_srand((double)microtime() * 10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
    $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
    $uuid = substr($charid, 0, 8)
            .substr($charid, 8, 4)
            .substr($charid, 12, 4)
            .substr($charid, 16, 4)
            .substr($charid, 20, 12);
    return $uuid;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your query to

```
$u = User::where('token',$token)// $token)
     ->first(['token']);
```

the get method gives you an array of object so an update/save can not be done directly on it as you are doing.  but with first() it gives you only one record from the database so it much easier to save or update it.